# Can't get my Rspec test of a JavaScript click event to pass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I need help troubleshooting an Rspec feature test of a Javascript click event in my Rails 4 application.  I'm using Capybara, FactoryGirl, and a seed file for data.  Poltergeist is the JavaScript driver for Capybara. The test that I'm having trouble with involves an image map where drop down menu options are selected when a user clicks hotspots. My application code works as expected in the browser. The script executes during the test as expected, but I'm having trouble writing a passing test (expectation).

Here's the relevant code from the spec file:

```
feature 'Clicking hotspots on image map' do

scenario 'selects chest muscle group', js:true do
  login
  expect(page).to have_content ("New Strength Exercise")
  #binding.pry
  page.execute_script("$('#map_chest_strength').click()")
  #save_and_open_page
  expect(page).to have_select("#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", with_options: "Chest - pectoralis")
end
end
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:
    Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_select("#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", with_options: "Chest - pectoralis")
       expected to find select box "#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id" with at least options "Chest - pectoralis" but there were no matches

**Here's relevant JavaScript/JQuery code:**

```
//Chest Muscle Group & Strength Exercise     
$("#map_chest_strength").click(function(){
    var chestID = 1;
    var muscle_group = $("#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id option[value='" + chestID + "']").attr("selected","selected");
    console.log(muscle_group);
 //Filters Strength Exercises by Chest Muscle Group        
    filterStrengthExercises();
 //Gets exercise description when user clicks muscle group via image map
    getDescription();
 }); // end image map - chest click event
```

Here's relevant HTML source:

```
<h4><span class="number">1</span>Choose target muscles</h4><br>
<label class="string optional" for="strength_exercise_muscle_group">Muscle group</label><br />
<select id="strength_exercise_muscle_group_id" name="strength_exercise[muscle_group_id]"><option value="">Your target muscles</option>
<option value="1">Chest - pectoralis</option></select>
```

The seed file is loaded in the test environment, and the click event fires as expected. "Chest - pectoralis" is selected as the drop-down option in the browser.  Why is my Rspec expectation failing?  What I'm I doing wrong, and how do I fix the test?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're doing the click through execute_script rather than `find('#map_chest_strength').click()` ?  Triggering it through JS doesn't always fire all the events that using the methods that try to emulate a user does.  Also - what version of poltergeist are you using, and can you show the JS that is supposed to be triggered by the click.

Comment: Originally, I wrote the test using "find('#map_chest_strength').click()", but Capaybara said it could not find the css.  I'm using     poltergeist (1.7.0).  See updated question with relevant JS/JQuery code.

Comment: Couple of things: Firstly the fact that Capybara couldn't find the css should concern you -- are you sure it's actually on the page and visible? (your execute_script wouldn't throw an error if the item wasn't even on the page) .  Secondly you should be using  `.prop("selected", true)` to set the options as selected rather than .attr   -   When you say "... works as expected in the browser" is that in production mode or only in dev mode?  It's possible you have JS errors in your code that are causing this since they get concatenated in test mode but not in dev mode

Comment: The code works as expected in both development and production mode (Heroku). The fact that Capybara couldn't find the css with find is a concern. The css is on the page and visible. I'm baffled about this.

Comment: OH -- just noticed - you have 'have_select("#strength_exercise_muscle_group_id" ...   -- remove the #  -- have_select takes the id not a css selector

Comment: I removed the #, and get the following NoMethodError:
       undefined method `all?' for "Chest - pectoralis":String

Comment: with_options takes an array - so   `expect(page).to have_select("strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", with_options: ["Chest - pectoralis"])  -- although if you want to check it's selected it would be  expect(page).to have_select("strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", selected: "Chest - pectoralis")

Comment: Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_select("strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", selected: "Chest - pectoralis")
       expected to find select box "strength_exercise_muscle_group_id" with "Chest - pectoralis" selected but there were no matches. Also found "Your target muscles Abs - rectus abdominis Biceps - biceps brachii Calves - gastrocnemius Chest - pectoralis Forearm - brachioradialis Lats - latissimus dorsi  Neck - sternocleidomastoid Quads - quadriceps Shoulders - deltoids Traps - trapezius Triceps - triceps brachii", which matched the selector but not all filters.

Comment: ok - so it's finding the select, but it doesnt appear to have the Chest - pectoralis selected  --- did you try swapping to .prop("selected", true)?

Comment: Changing to .prop("selected", true) did the trick!  expect(page).to have_select("strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", selected: "Chest - pectoralis") passes now.  Please write up your advice as an answer and I will accept it so you get credit for your work.  Tom, I really appreciate your help solving this problem,

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [have_select](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_select%3F-instance_method) matcher takes the label, name, or id of the select box (not a css selector), and the with_options takes an Array so it should be

```
expect(page).to have_select("strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", with_options: ["Chest - pectoralis"])
```

which will check that the select with at least the option "Chest - pectoralis" exists.  If you want to verify the select exists and that option is selected it would be

```
expect(page).to have_select("strength_exercise_muscle_group_id", selected: "Chest - pectoralis")
```

Note - the selected option can be an Array of strings if the select box is a multiple select

Also, in your JS you are using .attr("selected","selected") to set the selected state, that should really be  .prop("selected", true) (Same for all boolean attributes) which sets the elements property which is the correct indicator of whether or not an option is selected (rather than the attribute, which in this context is really only relevant at page load time)